# Variable changes state inside my singleton object

Tags: java, singleton

I've a singleton object responsible to start and stop an http server (using RESTlet framework).

When I create the object the `boolean` var `isStarted` is set to `false`. When the serve is started `isStarted` is set to `true`.

Here's is my code for the singleton:

```
private WebService() {
    this(Protocol.HTTP, DEFAULT_PORT);
}

private WebService(final Protocol protocol, final int port)
{
    this.protocol = protocol;
    this.port = port;
    this.isStarted = false;

    // Creating a new Restlet component and 
    this.component = new Component();
}

public synchronized static WebService getInstance()
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        return new WebService();
    }

    return instance;
}


public synchronized static WebService getInstance(final Protocol protocol, final int port)
{
    if(instance != null)
    {
        instance = null;
    }

    return new WebService(protocol, port);
}
```

Right now I'm just using the `getInstance()`, with no parameters.

Here is how I start and stop the server:

```
public synchronized boolean startServer(final Context context)
{
    if ( isStarted ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Tried to start a running server");
        throw new IllegalStateException("Tried to start a running server");
    }

    // Add a http connector to the component.
    component.getServers().add(protocol, port);
    component.getClients().add(Protocol.FILE);  

    // Static content
    // Attach the component to the localhost
    ipAuthenticator = new IPAuthenticator(org.restlet.Context.getCurrent());
    ContactsRouter contactsRouter = new ContactsRouter(context, ipAuthenticator);
    AuthenticationRouter authenticationRouter = new AuthenticationRouter(contactsRouter, ipAuthenticator);
    component.getDefaultHost().attach(authenticationRouter);

    // Start it! The HTTP server connector is also automatically started. 
    try {
        component.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        isStarted = false;
        return false;
    }

    isStarted = true;
    Log.d(TAG, "Server Started! and isStarted is: " + isStarted);

    return true;
}

public Boolean stopServer()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "WebService: isStarted: " + isStarted);
    if(isStarted)
    {
        try {
            component.stop();
            Log.d(TAG, "Server stopped");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception - Could not stop the server!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

My problem is when I start and stop the server using my app user interface I can start it with no problem but when I try to stop the server (after it has been started) I can't because `isStarted` is `false` when it should be `true`, as I just started the server previously.

Here is when I try to start/stop the server using my app Uuser Interface:

```
public HttpServer(ProgressBar progressBar, Context context, boolean isChecked)
{
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
    progressBar.setEnabled(false);
    this.context = context;
    webService = WebService.getInstance();
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
}

(...)

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // Hide the progress bar
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Here in this logcat I receive-> is sever started?: **false** but it should be true
    Log.d(TAG, "isChecked = " + isChecked + " || Is the server started?: " + webService.isStarted()); 

    if(isChecked == true)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Going to start the server");
        webService.startServer(context);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Going to stop the server");
        webService.stopServer();
    }
}
```

Again, my question is why, after the server is started, is `isChecked` false when it should be true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not affecting the singleton object

```
public synchronized static WebService getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new WebService();
        return instance;
    }
```

Comment: That's what I believe so as well but for some reason `isStarted` is changed and I understand why.

Comment: @dwnz I did not understand your comment. Are you saying this does not solve your issue? Have you updated getInstance() like I posted?

Comment: Oh. Nevermind, you are right. I should pay a bit more attention to what I see :) I looked at your code and thought you were just posting my method here. +1 and accepted. Thanks!